# VBA Counting Twice Loop?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, repeat

So I have my code which looks at names in columns I:L, and if the entry matches a name, it pastes the value of that row column A in another sheet. However, if a name appears twice in the same row in I:L it pastes the value in Column A twice. How can I fix this so that it only pastes Column A once if this happens?
Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)Dim r As Range, Vin As Variant, Vout As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, ct As Long, S As Long
Set Target = Target(1)
If Not Intersect(Range("M3"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set r = Range("I14:I59")
    r.ClearContents
    With Sheets("Master List").Range("I2:L1000" & Sheets("Master List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        Vin = .Value
        ReDim Vout(1 To UBound(Vin, 1))
        For i = 1 To UBound(Vin, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(Vin, 2)
                If Vin(i, j) = Target.Value Then
                    ct = ct + 1
                     S = i + 1
                    Vout(ct) = Sheets("Master List").Range("A" & S).Value
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
    If ct > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Vout(1 To ct)
        r.Resize(ct).Value = Application.Transpose(Vout)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Concatenate the values of I:L, use Instr for all of them, copy A; or If with four Or condition items, I, J, K, L.

Comment: Are the names going to be in any order? Can it be nameA nameB nameA or will it be nameA nameA nameB?

Comment: The names in I:L are in no order. It could be NameA in I, Name A in J, Name B in K, Name A in L

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're only looking for one name at a time, you can simply increment your row counter `i` as soon as you find it:

```
If Vin(i, j) = Target.Value Then
    ct = ct + 1
    S = i + 1
    Vout(ct) = Sheets("Master List").Range("A" & S).Value
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Comment: This fixes the double counting problem, but for some reason it now skips rows and doesn't paste all the values of column A. Any reason why?

Comment: I forgot to reset the value of `j`: Add `j=1` after `i=i+1` to start searching in column 1 again!